# How to make android and spring to exists together as modules in one project?

Tags: android, spring, kotlin, gradle

:) Last days I did some kotlin projects just for fun. Every project was created in kotlin as web app (spring) and mobile (android). I started to wondering if there is possibility to configure multimodule project where spring and android can be stored together as modules? I read some articles about multimodule projects but usually about web apps only. I tried doing something on my own but and nothing worked ;p
Here are my gradle files:

**setting.gradle.kts (spring web)**

```
rootProject.name = "web"
```

**build.gradle.kts (spring web)**

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.0.1"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.0"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.7.22"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.7.22"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.7.22"
}

group = "pl.mattiahit.myrestaurant.web"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.modelmapper:modelmapper:3.1.1")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    runtimeOnly("org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**build.gradle.kts (android)**

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "pl.mattiahit.myrestaurant.mobile"
    compileSdk = 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "pl.mattiahit.myrestaurant.mobile"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 32
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0")
    implementation("com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2")
    androidTestImplementation("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2")
}
```

**settings.gradle.kts (parent)**

```
rootProject.name = "MyRestaurant"

include("web")
include("mobile")
```

**build.gradle.kts (parent)**

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.0")
    }
}
```

Im getting error

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'MyRestaurant'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Cannot resolve external dependency org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.0 because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         project :
```

I have no experience with such projects... can anyone help me with that? Is there any good article about mulimodule projects etc ?

Answer (score 0):

As the error implies, you're missing the `repositories` block inside your top-level ("parent") `build.gradle.kts`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.0")
    }
}
```